# Override Column Design Best Practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have the following tables:

```
dbo.Order
ID SourceLinkID OverrideQueueID

dbo.SourceLink
ID SourceInputID SourceOutputID

dbo.QueueSourceLink
ID QueueID SourceLinkID

dbo.Queue
ID
```

Normally we would get the Queue for the Order by going from dbo.Order to dbo.QueueSourceLink. The user is allowed to override this Queue by saving a QueueID in the OverrideQueueID on the dbo.Order table. This essentially makes me have to perform a COALESCE or a UNION ALL on all of my queries that have to get the QueueID of an Order.

I am looking for suggestions on either redesign of this piece of the table, or better ways to handle this. I cannot put the QueueID in the dbo.Order table because the users can move the SourceLinkIDs at anytime to different queue's so I would have to update the dbo.Order table each time that happened if I were to do that. Once the dbo.Order is overwritten, it always remains overwritten so that is the final queue.

Comment: When the user overrides the QueueId, you could put it in the QueueSourceLink table instead of the Order table, and maybe include a "IsOverride" flag column if you need to do something special with the overrides.  Or instead of linking Order to QueueSourceLink, you could link it directly to Queue.

Comment: The user is overriding the queue only on that 1 Order, not on the whole SourceLinkID linkage. The other orders with that SourceLinkID remain in the same queue that they were in. What does the Order directly to Queue give me, wouldn't I still have to figure out if its overridden?

Comment: If you put QueueID in the Order table, instead of SourceLinkID, then you could also add the IsOverride flag to handle Overrides.  Also, if you link Order to QueueSourceLink with SourceLinkID, isn't it possible to get multiple QueueIDs if the same SourceLinkID is tied to more than one QueueID?